# WP/WooComm Adding a variable to a complicated shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have a shortcode where I need to dynamically insert the current WordPress/ WooCommerce category to it.

The raw shortcode is

```
[content_control]
[product_table category="product-cateegory-name" columns="sku,name,cf:size,cf:pgk_qty,cf:case_qty,cf:case_wt,stock,price,buy,cf:dia_pitch,cf:length,cf:inner_box_q,cf:inner_box_length,cf:inner_box_width,cf:inner_box_height,cf:outer_box_qty,cf:outer_box_length,cf:outer_box_width,cf:outer_box_height,cf:outer_box_weight" column_breakpoints="all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none"]
[/content_control]
```

I was trying

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[content_control]"); ?>
<php 
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_slug;
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_table category="'. $cateID .'" columns="sku,name,cf:size,cf:pgk_qty,cf:case_qty,cf:case_wt,stock,price,buy,cf:dia_pitch,cf:length,cf:inner_box_q,cf:inner_box_length,cf:inner_box_width,cf:inner_box_height,cf:outer_box_qty,cf:outer_box_length,cf:outer_box_width,cf:outer_box_height,cf:outer_box_weight" column_breakpoints="all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none"]"); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[/content_control]"); ?>
```

But I think inserting the variable this way won't work.

I think there is something basic I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I had to escape the `"`s within the PHP and connect the two arguments in the shortcode via a `' . '`

````
$cate = get_queried_object()->slug;
echo do_shortcode("[product_table category=\"' . $cate . ' \" columns=\"sku,name,cf:size,cf:pgk_qty,cf:case_qty,cf:case_wt,stock,price,buy,cf:dia_pitch,cf:length,cf:inner_box_q,cf:inner_box_length,cf:inner_box_width,cf:inner_box_height,cf:outer_box_qty,cf:outer_box_length,cf:outer_box_width,cf:outer_box_height,cf:outer_box_weight\"' . 'column_breakpoints=\"all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,all,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none\"']"); ?>```
````